# 500 ошибка gitlab

Tags: linux, docker, gitlab

Перенес базу с одного сервера на другой(версии и прочее-совпадают) база была в gz архиве после того как распаковал ее и заменил. При распаковке было почему-то много ошибок непонятных для меня, но подгрузили проекты и прочее. Если из admin area нажать на вкладке с проектами на них, то выпадает 500 ошибка. Остальной функционал работает исправно. gitlab запущен с помощью docker-compose файла, psql также.
Вопрос: Как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: Если бы посмотреть на ошибки распаковки... Я думаю, что в логах, всё "черным-по-белому" написано.

Answer (score 0):

[посмотреть логи](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/logs.html) работы приложений (gitlab) и найти ошибки, после этого можно будет понять, что делать дальше.

Используйте [tail для слежения за логом в реальном времени](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/logs.html#tail-logs-in-a-console-on-the-server) (пример для пакета). Перейдите на страницу с ошибкой и посмотрите в лог. Для Rails приложений вывод "многословный", но если внимательно "двигаться вверх" к началу сообщения об исключении, то вы обнаружите понятное описание ошибки. Ошибки могут быть совсем простыми, например: нет прав на запись.

Плюс:

- Проверьте системный лог сервера
- Еще раз проверьте рекомендации разработчика по миграции на другой сервер

> '... почему-то много ошибок непонятных для меня ...'  внимательно проанализировать ошибки и если это возможно устранить их причину.

После того, как ошибки были обнаружены, можно будет задать вопросы по каждой из них.

Comment: Посмотреть еще в самом начале посмотрел, а вот понять что там написано не смог.

Comment: Надо найти ошибки, тогда решение будет. Думаю надо начать с ошибок распаковки, а потом уже двигаться дальше.

Comment: может быть я вам скрины с ошибкой скину?

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/80699/gitlab-docker-fail?tab=general

Comment: не могу писать тк репутации нет

Comment: ну тогда можно залить куда-нибудь (joxy, yandex, drive)

Comment: вроде как вот [это](https://yadi.sk/i/SU0Cj7JO3ZbNH6)

Comment: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/27635

Comment: Сейчас попробую. Можно еще попросить вас глянуть мою тему, пожалуйста? [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/859145/%d0%a1%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%85%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%bf-lda-%d0%b2-gitlab)